# Android Wear, startActivityForResult not working from custom display intent notification

Tags: android, wear-os

When starting an activity from an activity embedded in a wear side notification (using `WearableExtender.setDisplayIntent`), activity is not drawn/rendered properly when 2nd activity finishes, just a black screen. Activities/pages to left/right render properly.

Problem Description:
- Activity `DisplayActivity` (embedded as display intent):

```
    <activity
        android:name=".DisplayActivity"
        android:allowEmbedded="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:taskAffinity=""/>
```

- Activity `StartedActivity`:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".StartedActivity"
        android:allowEmbedded="true"
        android:exported="true"
        />
```

- Embed DisplayActivity in a wear-side notification
- From DisplayActivity, start StartedActivity using Activity.startActivityForResult with new task flags (`intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK  | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)`)
- Finish `DisplayActivity` by swiping to right or by clicking some button that calls `Activity.finish()`;
- Returning to notification, but `DisplayActivity` is black and doesn't recognize touch input. Swipe to left/right pages works.

Expected:
DisplayActivity to render correctly.

```
Device: Samsung Gear Live
Software version: 4.4W
Build number: KMV78Y
```

Answer (score 1):

Opened https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=74882 for this problem, changing from `Activity.startActivityForResult()` to `Activity.startActivity()` seems to be a workaround.